# Can't hear sound using ofSoundStream on Emscripten

Tags: emscripten, openframeworks

I found out `ofSoundStream` based examples don't work properly on Emscripten.
Here' my minimal example code that works on macOS but doesn't work on Emscripten.

**`ofApp.h`**:

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{
    public:
    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();

    void keyPressed(int key);
    void keyReleased(int key);
    void mouseMoved(int x, int y);
    void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
    void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
    void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button);
    void mouseEntered(int x, int y);
    void mouseExited(int x, int y);
    void windowResized(int w, int h);
    void dragEvent(ofDragInfo dragInfo);
    void gotMessage(ofMessage msg);

    void audioOut(ofSoundBuffer & buffer); //only this is added
};
```

**`ofApp.cpp`**: (only relevant methods)

```
#include "ofApp.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::setup(){

    ofSoundStreamSettings settings;
    settings.numInputChannels = 0;
    settings.numOutputChannels = 2;
    settings.sampleRate = 44100;
    settings.bufferSize = 512;
    settings.setOutListener(this);
    ofSoundStreamSetup(settings);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::audioOut(ofSoundBuffer & buffer)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer.getNumFrames(); ++i)
    {
        buffer[i*buffer.getNumChannels()    ] = ofRandom(0, 1) * 0.1;
        buffer[i*buffer.getNumChannels() + 1] = ofRandom(0, 1) * 0.1;
    }
}
```

Result: When I run it, it says `Exception thrown, see JavaScript console`.
[image]

In the Javascript console, I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Runtime.dynCall is not a function at
>   ScriptProcessorNode.stream.onaudioprocess

[image]

In the Terminal console, I get no specific message.
And of course, I hear no sound at all.

I found out `ofxEmscriptenSoundStream::audio_cb()` function is not being called at all although its function pointer is passed to `html5audio_stream_create()` function when `ofxEmscriptenSoundStream::setup()` is called.

`html5audio_stream_create` function is implemented in `library_html5audio.js` file and I think the following part is where it calls the `ofxEmscriptenSoundStream::audio_cb()` function:

> `Runtime.dynCall('viiii',callback,[bufferSize,inputChannels,outputChannels,userData]);`

However I have no idea why it fails to call the callback function. (I can't code JS)

How can I make `ofSoundStream` properly work on Emscripten?

Comment: Please post the "Javascript console"(or browser console), not terminal console.

Comment: @BumsikKim Thank you I just added the JS console result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this issue by changing `Runtime.dynCall` to just `dynCall` in `library_html5audio.js` file.

I followed the advice from [this post](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/8018#issuecomment-461254828):

> The Runtime object has been removed for quite some time at this point (to fix that issue, you should remove Runtime. from your code, and just call dynCall).

After the fix and rebuilding the project, I could successfully hear the sound on a Chrome browser.